# ¿Cómo usar fechas distintas de dos tablas diferentes en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Espero me apoyen con mi dilema.

Tengo dos tablas una de facturas y otra de pagos. Las facturas quedan con fecha de emisión y los pagos con la fecha de pago.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente tengo una consulta que me da la información de total facturado, total pagado y saldo por almacén por vendedor y por mes.

```
SELECT
dbo.A_detareport.DepotName,
dbo.A_detareport.SalesRep,
SUM(dbo.A_detareport.Total) AS Total,
SUM(dbo.A_detareport.TotalPaid) AS Pagado,
SUM(dbo.A_detareport.Balance) AS Saldo
FROM
dbo.A_detareport
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.docDocumentPayment ON dbo.A_detareport.Total = dbo.docDocumentPayment.Amount AND dbo.docDocumentPayment.DocumentID = dbo.A_detareport.DocumentID
WHERE
(dbo.A_detareport.Cancelled = 0) AND (dbo.A_detareport.Deleted = 0) AND (dbo.A_detareport.DateDocument >= '2021-03-01') AND (dbo.A_detareport.DateDocument <= '2021-03-31')
GROUP BY dbo.A_detareport.DepotName, dbo.A_detareport.SalesRep
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema se da cuando la factura es de un mes (fecha) y el pago de otro mes (fecha), por que me esta sumando el total pagado al mes de la fecha de la factura y lo que quiero es que si la factura se pago en otro mes distinto a su emisión se sume al mes en el que se pago.

Ya intente en el *where* filtrar por fecha de pago o emisión, pero solo me muestra las pagadas o no pagadas con *betweeen*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola buen día, para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y se te pueda ayudar, te invito a que veas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ya que en tu caso las consultas tienen que ir como Texto.

Comment: Y adicional, en tu caso lo que tienes que hacer es dos consultas, una donde obtienes el total facturado de el mes, y otra donde obtienes el total de pagos, pueden ser dos consultas y llenar a una temporal, o dos subconsultas y unirlas, que que yo iría por la primera, por que algún caso especifico puedes tener resultados en la segunda consulta de pagos y no de facturas.

Comment: gracias por tus comentarios, intentare lo que me comentas.

Comment: ¿Que pasa cuando una factura fue emitida en enero y el pago en marzo, en qué mes debe reflejarse y cómo?

Comment: en marzo, ya que no importa la fecha en la que se realizo si no cuando se pago esto por el tema de saldos. si se refleja con el total pagado se sumaria a ese mes.

Comment: el total facturado nuca se mueve será el mismo en ese mes a menos que cancelen una factura,  pero el total pagado si, depende mucho de la fecha de pago.

Comment: @gera, la tu respuesta no es nada clara. No me dices con precisión ni cuando tiene que aparecer el total de la factura ni cuando el pagado. Espero una respuesta del tipo: Sumaría al total en enero y al pagado en marzo. O ambos sumarían en marzo, o se excluye el total en todos los meses y solo se muestra el pagado en marzo, o algo específico que ayude a entender qué es lo que realmente buscas.

Comment: entiendo, si una factura se hizo en marzo debería aparecer en total facturado del mes de marzo, si a esa misma factura se le aplica pago en abril debería sumar al total pagado del mes de abril y ya no es necesario que aparezca en total facturado puesto que no se hizo en ese mes de abril sino en marzo

Comment: ahorita lo que hace es que no importa el mes que se pague, el total pagado me los suma en marzo y no se pago en marzo se pago en abril yo quiero que sume ese total PAGADO a abril. Espero ahora sea contundente, gracias por tus comentarios.